# sshd does not recognise "AllowUsers user@host" statements

Tags: networking, ip, hosts, sshd

I recently installed Fedora-25, and I am having a problem with my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  I am trying to configure it with a statement like:

```
AllowUsers user@host
```

I cannot connect via ssh to the target computer. Instead, I get an error message in the target's `/var/log/secure` logfile: "...not listed in AllowUsers".  The user name is correct, the host is listed in `/etc/hosts`.

Here is what I have tried:

- When I replace the host name with its IP address, then it works.
- when I start the ssh daemon on the target computer in foreground for debugging (`/sbin/sshd -d`), then it works also with host name instead of IP.
- When I omit the host name altogether (i.e., "AllowUsers user"), then it works as expected, but I want a client-specific configuration.
- I tried `UseDNS no`, but this does not affect the situation.
- I checked `/etc/nsswitch.conf`; everything looks correct to me.

Obviously, since it works with IPs, it is not a big problem for me. However, I'd prefer to use host names. I would also like to understand what in this case is the difference between host and IP, and why host names no longer work.

Previously I had Fedora-21 installed, and host names worked in that version.

Any explanations welcome.

Comment: You have modified the `/etc/hosts` file and defined these hostnames and connected them to their ips?  If you said this in your question, and I missed it, I blame the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

This question is more than a year old, but `UseDNS yes` should fix it for you, as it just did for me.

You say you tried `UseDNS no`, but that is the default anyway, so that changes nothing.

The `UseDNS` option is mis-named in my opinion, the OpenSSH team should have called it `UseNameResolution`, as `no` seems to prevent `/etc/hosts` look-up as well, and presumably all other methods also.

Comment: FYI, this solution worked for me, AFTER I configured my **/etc/hosts** file as specified by **Ramhound** in his comment to the OP. *Debian Stretch - OpenSSH 7.4p1*.